# Рисование фигур в окне JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, рисование

Есть окно `JFrame`, и 2 переменные: `х` и `у`.

Задача: 10 раз в секунду отрисовывать черный квадратик по координатам `х` и `у`.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Точно десять раз в секунду? Может, раз в десять секунд?

Comment: Возможно. Интересует код, настроить время могу сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как вообще нарисовать квадрат?**

1. Создайте какой-нибудь класс, который будет наследоваться от `javax.swing.JPanel`. В нём переопределите метод `paintComponent(Graphics g)`:

```java
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

  }

}
```

2. В переопределённом методе нарисуйте фигуры. Прямоугольники и квадраты можно рисовать с помощью метода `fillRect()`. Этот метод принимает на вход четыре параметра: `int x`, `int y`, `int width`, `int height`.

Из документации:

> x - the x coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.

> y - the y coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.

> width - the width of the rectangle to be filled.

> height - the height of the rectangle to be filled.

Вольный перевод:

> x - координата по оси x левого верхнего угла прямоугольника

> y - координата по оси y левого верхнего угла прямоугольника

> width - ширина прямоугольника

> heigth - высота прямоугольника

Чтобы нарисовать квадрат, укажите одинаковую высоту и ширину. Это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```java
g.fillRect(50, 50, 20, 20);
```

При таком вызове метода будет нарисован квадрат, левый верхний угол которого находится по координате `50, 50` и имеет высоту 20 пикселей и такую же ширину.

3. Теперь самое важное - нужно "привязать" нарисованное к окну

Сделать это проще всего, используя полиморфизм:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Это квадрат");
JPanel panel = new GraphicsPanel(); //Используем полиморфизм
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

Важно: не забудьте отобразить фрейм и задать ему размер  =).

**Как его рисовать раз в десять секунд?**

1. Создайте в классе с переопределённым методом `paintComponent()` поле типа `boolean`. Я назову его `hide` и сделаю его статическим:

```java
public static boolean hide;
```

2. В методе `painComponent()` пропишите, что рисовать квадрат нужно только если значение поля `hide` равно `false`:

```java
if(hide == false){
   g.fillRect(50, 50, 20, 20);
}
```

3. С помощью класса `java.util.Timer` меняйте значение переменной `hide` раз в какое-то время. Проще всего для этого использовать анонимный класс:

```java
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
   @Override 
   public void run(){
      if(GraphicsPanel.hide == true){
         hide = false;
      } else {
         hide = true;
      }
      frame.repaint();
  }
}, 0, 10000); //Второй параметр - это время, через которое будет каждый раз срабатывать таймер.
```

Важно: не забудьте импортировать классы `java.util.Timer` и `java.util.TimerTask`!

**P.S**

если вам нужно нарисовать **не**закрашенный прямоугольник, то используйте метод `drawRect()`. Вызывать его нужно точно так же.

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, то пожалуйста, примите его как решение =). Если остались вопросы, то задавайте их.

Comment: Спасибо! Объяснили понятно, даже очень)

Comment: @user526377 я ещё немного подправил ответ, забыл, что для таймера нужно время установить. Оно указывается в миллисекундах (см. ответ).

Comment: Некоторые настройки включая координаты находятся в основном классе Main. Как я могу их перенести в класс отрисовки?

Comment: @user526377 вы имеете в виду, что переменные `x` и `y` вас находятся в классе Main?

Comment: Да, и некоторые другие переменные

Comment: @user526377 Просто поместите эти переменные в поле класса `Main`. Желательно их сделать приватными, а доступ к ним получать через сеттеры и геттеры.